# Error in a simple Keras ANN MNIST data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting the following error while compiling the neural network on MNIST data set

```
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

```
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000]/255.0, X_train_full[5000:]/255.0
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28,28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=30,validation_data=(X_valid,y_valid))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using integer label (check `y_train[:5]`), that's why you should not use `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function, instead use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

FYI, if you one-hot encoded the label using `tf.one_hot(y_train, 10)`, then you can use `categorical_crossentropy` loss function.